# How to determine the dimensions of an array by the length of a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I wanted to display a varying number of images today in matplotlib subplot and ran into an interesting question I thought was simple but I can't seem to figure out. Don't worry about how to display it, I'm just wondering about the algorithm.

**The Problem:**

*Given a n length list of images determine the most square/efficient matrix to represent them.*

**Examples:**

Given the following number of images, the output matrix would be ideal.

3 -> [2,2]

5 -> [2,3] or [3,2]

12 -> [4,3] or [3,4]

22 -> [5,5] is better than [6,4] for squareness but not efficiency

33 - > [6,6] or [7,5] for efficiency

I couldn't find the answer anywhere so I figured it would be fun to get some ideas. This is the code I was going to implement.

```
    for i in range(list_size):
        plt.subplot(0, 0, i + 1), plt.imshow(image_list[i], 'gray')
        plt.title(image_name[i])
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: Uh, take the square root of the input?

Comment: divide length by every integer value smaller or equal to square root of length and see which result gives integer result. This way you can find all dimentions. Now you have to decide which one to use. Maybe the last one - so you could start divied by `int(sqrt(33))`, next by `int(sqrt(33))-1`, next `int(sqrt(33))-2`, etc..

Comment: How does that determine the best matrix? sqrt(5) = 2.2, sqrt(33)=5.7 how would I get 2,3 from 5 with this method? Am I just not seeing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aran-Fey is probably on the right track.  Depending on whether you want a tall or wide aspect ratio, you could start by calculating an integer number of rows or columns based on a square.  Integer columns gives a tall result because the "mod" type remainder will be added as a partial row below the squared part.

For a Square matrix that adds a partial row to the end...

> matrixCols = int(sqrt(list_len))
>
> ## round up to number of integer rows
>
> matrixRows = math.ceil(list_len / matrixCols)

For a square matrix that adds a partial column to the end...

> matrixRows = int(sqrt(list_len))
>
> ## round up to number of integer columns
>
> matrixCols = math.ceil(list_len / matrixCols)

It does seem that the most efficient matrix array is the one that sizes the images based on what will fit onto the screen/window until the size hits the smallest visible/usable image size and scrolls from there.  The most efficient row/col matrix is going to depend on the aspect ratio of your screen/window.

Comment: This is good for efficiency but not squareness. I was thinking of following the square root path but then incrementing and decrementing values and checking if they are square and passing. As in, 33 -> [7,5] in your method and then I could try incrementing and decrementing the two values to try and get 6,6 and then checking.

Comment: It does optimize true squareness--which is the most efficient use of screen space on average.  The exception being when the residual is very small (such as when the list_len yields a SQRT with a small decimal).

It sounds like you'd like to search for integer areas where possible.  In such a case, you'll have an optimization algorithm that looks for the smallest delta between the rows and columns AND also gives the largest non-integer remainder.

Comment: In such a case, you'll have an optimization algorithm that looks for the smallest delta between the number of rows and columns AND also gives the largest non-integer remainder.  Recurse through numColumns 1 to (list_len / 2), creating a dictionary as you go of the numColumns and sqrt() decimal remainder.  The optimal balance of minimal area and maximal "fullness" of rows and columns will be in the neighborhood of the int(sqrt(list_len)).  You can start some arbitrary number of dict entries before int(sqrt) and search for the largest decimal remainder.

Comment: The optimal in terms of both footprint and "fullness" of rows & cols is going to be in the neighborhood of the sqrt() value.  Parse through (list_len / cols) and create a dict of the divisor and decimal remainder.  Start some arbitrary number of entries before the sqrt() and find the largest remainder (including 1.000) or smallest (1-remainder).